# Don't show .svn folders in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-pdt

In Eclipse, the PHP Explorer view (that shows the folders of the project) is polluted by the .svn folders. That's kind of annoying, is there a way to hide them, because I looked everywhere in the documentation and didn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you asked this.  Until now I had been tolerating this ><

Answer (score 5, accepted):

almost every view like explorer and outline views in eclipse has an option to filter visible elements by regex. you can find the menu by clicking on the small downward-pointing trangle in the top right corner of the view, then select the **Filters** item, then click the **name filter patterns** box, type sth like `*svn` and voila.

Comment: Thank you ! Well it turned out that the view was already supposed to filter everything starting with ".", so the .svn should not appear. But when i specifically add ".svn" in the filter, I still see them. So I guess that's an Eclipse bug (among maaaany others) and I am to lazy to reinstall once again. But I personalized the filter to be able to see the .htaccess, so I am happy :)

Comment: kostja: .* resources are already selected in filters and .settings and .htaccess are both hidden, however I still see the .svn folder. My install of Eclipse is clean (Version: Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110218-0911)

Answer (score 5):

Open up eclipse and right click on your project in the workspace. Choose Properties and then select resource. Add a resource filter of type ‘exclude’ Enter the .svn folder name and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't use Subclipse for actual SVN access, I find that installing it is useful in that it does remove all the .svn folders from your project's view AND it give's you visual cues as to a given file's status with respect to SVN in general.  Kind of a high price to pay though ...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to install a Subversion plugin into Eclipse (like Subclipse or Subversive)...

Comment: +1 I use Subclipse and I've never had to see those `.svn` folders.

Comment: This is a very intrusive solution in my opinion. On the same level, you could have said "the best solution is to switch to Netbeans". I'm not saying this agressively though ;)