# How to hide .svn folder in Eclipse and not show empty packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

How can I hide .svn folder in Eclipse and not show empty packages at the same time?

[image]

Eclipse shows these packages because there is a .svn folder there.

I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Package Explorer you have the option "Filters..." (click on the small triangle) where you can filter empty packages.

Comment: additional details / similar q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829075/dont-show-svn-folders-in-eclipse

Answer (score 5):

What natros said.  More info for users of Eclipse Helios:

Go to **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Resource** -> **Resource Filters** and add a filter that excludes all folders where name matches '.svn'.

Don't forget to check the 'All children (recursive)' box.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) plugin.
Eclipse will hide the .svn folders and start supporting SVN natively through Team menu.

Comment: Strange. I don't have the filter activated and I still don't see empty packages. You should use Subversive anyway.

Comment: Subversive is definitely more robust in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have SVN plugin installed in Eclipse. It should do the magic. Try [Eclipse's Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)

Comment: I have subclipse installed.  It does not appear to hide the .svn directories.  (Perhaps things have changed since 2011.)